# Can anyone tell me what's keeping this code from rendering correctly? I feel so close

Tags: javascript, function, object

1. Browser is telling me the problem might lie with the checkForMatch() and the flipCard
2. To be specific, it says cardId is undefined.

   ```
   const cards = [
       {
           rank: "queen",
           suite: "hearts",
           cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
       },
       {
           rank: "queen",
           suite: "diamonds",
           cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
       },
       {
           rank: "king",
           suite: "hearts",
           cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
       },
       {
           rank: "king",
           suite: "diamonds",
           cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
       }
   ];


   let cardsInPlay = [];

   function checkForMatch() {
       this.setAttribute('src', cards[cardId].cardImage);
       if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
           if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
               console.log("You found a match!");
           } else {
               console.log("Sorry, try again.");
           }
       }
   }

   function flipCard() {
       const cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
       console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
       console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
       console.log(cards[cardId].suite);
       cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
       checkForMatch();
   }


   function createBoard() {
       for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
           let cardElement = document.createElement('img');
           cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
           cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
           cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
           document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
       }
   }

   createBoard();
   ```

Comment: When you call a function, the function being called doesn’t inherit the variables available in the caller. Look into *parameters* to get the value of `cardId` from `flipCard` to `checkForMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `cardId` variable as a parameter from the `flipCard` function into the `checkForMatch` function.

So at the end of the flipCard function you need to do:

```
checkForMatch(cardId);
```

And in the checkForMatch function declaration (right at the top of the function), you need to do:

```
function checkForMatch(cardId) {
```

Comment: appreciate it a lot